# Android moveTaskToBack() does not work after I restart my MAIN activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is my onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        moveTaskToBack(false);
    }
}
```

And this is the way in which I restart my MAIN activity:

```
public void restart() {
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**moveTaskToBack** works well before I restart it.
But it no longer works after restarting.
What should I do?

Comment: please provide full code for Activity

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
One way is to replace **moveTaskToBack(false);** with **moveTaskToBack(true);**.
But that does not solve the problem actually.
The real solution is to add finish(); after restart another activity so that the new one will be the root activity.
Now the codes are like this:

```
public void restart() {
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening Fragment from DrawerMainActivity.java then this link help you [Handle Back Pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972103/how-to-keep-only-one-instance-of-a-fragment-when-switching-with-navigationdrawe/39404623#39404623)