# Prevent same fragments in backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have one Activity. In this activity, multiple fragments are there.
Fragments are in sequence to add,
A -> B -> C -> D -> B -> C -> D

Now, when i back action perform than sequence is,
D <- C <- B <- D <- C <- B <- A

But I have to perform back stack like this,
D <- C <- B <- A

what is the proper way to prevent the same Fragment in the backStack?

Here is my code for adding fragments,

```
 if (fragment != null) {
            val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            if (bundle != null)
                fragment.arguments = bundle
                transaction.add(R.id.container_body, fragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragTag)
                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit()
        }
```

And also for backstack perform,

```
 if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep only one instance of a fragment, when switching with NavigationDrawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972103/how-to-keep-only-one-instance-of-a-fragment-when-switching-with-navigationdrawe)

Comment: Yes, thank you. It will work good @PrakashReddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the fragment set a tag for it, then later you can find it through the fragment manager and replace/create new one accordingly

```
FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = fManager.findFragmentByTag("uniqueTag");

// If fragment doesn't exist yet, create one
if (fragment == null) {
     fTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_list, new ListFrag(), "uniqueTag");
 }else { // re-use the old fragment
     fTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list, fragment, "uniqueTag");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is perfect, but once I had done something like this. I had a stack of type integers (let's call it `stackOfFragmentTracker`). So suppose you have fragments f1, f2, f3, f4 and you did f1->f3->f4->f2. Then `stackOfFragmentTracker` would have content like this: 1->3->4->2.

Next, you create only one instance per fragment (so in my example, say f1, f2, f3, f4 each have only one instance) and you would keep them in backStack in INVISIBLE state:

```
final int ONE = 1; // a map to Fragment 1
final int TWO = 2; // a map to fragment 2

stackOfFragmentTracker.push(ONE);
ExampleFragment f1 = null;
        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ExampleFragment.TAG)==null){
            f1 = new ExampleFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.flToMountOn, f1, ExampleFragment.TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(ExampleFragment.TAG)
                    .hide(f1)  // <------- this makes your fragment invisible
                    .commit();
        }
```

You would do that for all of your fragments.

Next, you need a Fragment variable (say, `Fragment active`), point it to your first fragment (i.e, where you want to go for the 1st time) and make it visible.

```
active = f1;
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(f1).commit();
```

To keep things clean, you can use these 2 methods:

```
    private void hideActiveFragment(){
        if(currentlyActiveFragment!=null){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(currentlyActiveFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    private void showActiveFragment(Fragment nextFragment){
        active = nextFragment;
        if(active!=null){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(active).commit();
        }
    }
```

Finally, whenever you go forward, you would push a number into `stackOfFragmentTracker` and simply make that fragment visible:

```
// say we are going to f2

void switchFragment(int n){
  stackOfFragmentTracker.push(n); // you may keep a check if n is valid or not
  if(n==1){
    hideActiveFragment();
    showActiveFragment(f1);
  }else if(n==2){
    hideActiveFragment();
    showActiveFragment(f2);
  } // ... ... ...
}
```

And `onBackPress` do this:

```
void insideBackPress(){
  stackOfFragmentTracker.pop();
  int top = stackOfFragmentTracker.top();
 if(top==1){
    hideActiveFragment();
    showActiveFragment(f1);
  }else if(top==2){
    hideActiveFragment();
    showActiveFragment(f2);
  } // ... ... ...
}
```

I know the example is a bit messy, but I hope you get the point. Add necessary checks for various corner cases (if stackOfFragmentTracker isEmpty), or use a `HashMap` instead of the `if-else` block in my example. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dismiss() like if you go A to B, B To C and C to D when you press back and dismiss the fragment its removed from queue like its go like this D to C and C to B and B to A its make your stack clear and essay to handle